# Looping around a whole data step in SAS

Tags: sas

So I have a following code:

%let macroVar = Var1 Var2;

```
Data new1;
Set old1 (keep= count &macroVar.);
Run;

Proc means data = new1 nway missing noprint;
Class var1;
Var count;
Output out= out_var1 sum=;

Proc means data = new1 nway missing noprint;
Class var2;
Var count;
Output out= out_var2 sum=;
```

How can I write out the two proc means in one data step, using the macro variable I set up at the beginning?

Many thanks

Comment: Did you try creating a macro to loop over the list of variables?

Answer (score 0):

Why not just do it in one PROC MEANS call?

```
%let varlist=sex age ;
proc means data=sashelp.class missing noprint;
  class &varlist;
  ways 1;
  var height;
  output out=want sum=;
run;
```

Result:

```
Obs    Sex    Age    _TYPE_    _FREQ_    Height

 1             11       1         2       108.8
 2             12       1         5       297.2
 3             13       1         3       184.3
 4             14       1         4       259.6
 5             15       1         4       262.5
 6             16       1         1        72.0
 7      F       .       2         9       545.3
 8      M       .       2        10       639.1
```

If you really must have separate output datasets then it will be faster to generate them from the output above.

```
%macro sum_counts(varlist,data=,var=count);
%local i n;
%let n=%sysfunc(countw(&varlist));

proc means data=&data missing noprint ;
  class &varlist;
  ways 1;
  var &var;
  output out=_summary_ sum=;
run;

%do i=1 %to &n;
  data new&i;
    set _summary_;
    where _type_=2**(&n-&i);
    keep %scan(&varlist,&i) &var;
  run;
%end;

%mend sum_counts;
```

Example:

```
263   options mprint;
264   %sum_counts(varlist=sex age,data=sashelp.class,var=height);
MPRINT(SUM_COUNTS):   proc means data=sashelp.class missing noprint ;
MPRINT(SUM_COUNTS):   class sex age;
MPRINT(SUM_COUNTS):   ways 1;
MPRINT(SUM_COUNTS):   var height;
MPRINT(SUM_COUNTS):   output out=_summary_ sum=;
MPRINT(SUM_COUNTS):   run;

NOTE: There were 19 observations read from the data set SASHELP.CLASS.
NOTE: The data set WORK._SUMMARY_ has 8 observations and 5 variables.

MPRINT(SUM_COUNTS):   data new1;
MPRINT(SUM_COUNTS):   set _summary_;
MPRINT(SUM_COUNTS):   where _type_=2**(2-1);
MPRINT(SUM_COUNTS):   keep sex height;
MPRINT(SUM_COUNTS):   run;

NOTE: There were 2 observations read from the data set WORK._SUMMARY_.
      WHERE _type_=2;
NOTE: The data set WORK.NEW1 has 2 observations and 2 variables.

MPRINT(SUM_COUNTS):   data new2;
MPRINT(SUM_COUNTS):   set _summary_;
MPRINT(SUM_COUNTS):   where _type_=2**(2-2);
MPRINT(SUM_COUNTS):   keep age height;
MPRINT(SUM_COUNTS):   run;

NOTE: There were 6 observations read from the data set WORK._SUMMARY_.
      WHERE _type_=1;
NOTE: The data set WORK.NEW2 has 6 observations and 2 variables.
```

Comment: I know this would work in terms of getting out the data however it makes my next piece of analysis more difficult. And if I could create them as two separate files it will be more efficient for the overall process.